# What script would concatenate strings and filter by column value?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, relational-database

I need a script that will concatenate the Reason values by PLAN_ID in a colon delimited string from the following table and place them in a further table, staying true to the Order value. How can this be achieved?

```
PLAN_ID Order   Reason
6281    1       Declined
6281    4       Unfit
6281    8       Other
6281    9       Monitoring
6286    1       Declined
6286    5       Unknown Site
6286    10      Not Known

PLAN_ID Reason
6281    Declined;Unfit;Other;Monitoring
6286    Declined;Unknown Site;Not Known
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should work:

```
SELECT  t1.plan_id, 
        STUFF(( SELECT  '; ' + t2.reason 
                FROM    orders AS t2 
                WHERE   t1.plan_id = t2.plan_id
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') as reason
FROM    dbo.orders AS t1 
GROUP BY plan_id
```

You can insert the output of the above SELECT statement into desired table using simple INSERT INTO..SELECT syntax.